# jquery nicescroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, nicescroll

I'm using nicescroll plugin. http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

I have just a little doubt. When the page is loaded I can see my default scroll bar from the browser, and then the nicescroll bar it is showed. I want to apply the nicescroll bar to all the document and I have the following code

```
var nice = $("body").niceScroll({
        preservenativescrolling: false,
        cursorwidth: '8px',
        cursorborder: 'none',
        cursorborderradius:'0px',
        cursorcolor:"#39CCDB",
        autohidemode: false, 
        background:"#999999"
     });
```

If I set the autohidemode to true, I don't see the default scroll bar from the browser. But I want to make the nicescroll bar always visible.

Does anyone know why this is happening??
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this might help you. It works for me.

```
<script id="twitter-wjs" src="../js/widgets.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>


<script>

  // Hide Overflow of Body on DOM Ready //
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
});

// Show Overflow of Body when Everything has Loaded //
$(window).load(function(){
    $("body").css("overflow", "visible");        
    var nice=$('html').niceScroll({cursorborder:"",cursorcolor:"#333333",cursorwidth:"8px", boxzoom:true, autohidemode:false});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of what you might want:

```js
if (jQuery().niceScroll) {
    $("html").niceScroll({
        scrollspeed: 70,
        mousescrollstep: 38,
        cursorwidth: 15,
        cursorborder: 0,
        cursorcolor: '#0C090A',
        cursorborderradius: 0,
        autohidemode: true,
        horizrailenabled: false
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to make your classes `.nicescroll` elements `overflow:hidden;` inside your css, so the scrollbars won't appear,

than after your document loads (preferabily on window.load) apply the nicescroll plugin and set your elements to `overflow:auto` with jQuery like:

CSS:

```
.nicescroll{overflow:hidden;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $('.nicescroll').css({overflow:'auto'});
});
```

I think in your case you'd have to add an ID or a class (like in my example) to your `body` element.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. It's a good idea. But doesnt work because (and I dont know why) the scroll bar from nicescroll doesn't show up. It is only visible the default scroll bar from the browser

Comment: @user794035 mh, really sorry to hear that. Tried my best as I still have not experiences with this plugin. But as soon I'll need it  and find a solution (or perhaps - create my own) you'll be the first to know

Comment: OK thanks. When I saw your code for me it make sense, but perhaps the problem is that the nicescroll reads the height of the .nicescroll when the document is ready. But I tried to call him after the window is loaded  but I got the same results. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay! Here's a solution from me. I had same issue. I applied so many methods but they didn't work for me. Then after searching for weeks I found this solution. I am using the **latest version** of niceScroll and it's  **v-3.7.6**

**Html:-**

```html
<div id="scrollable-div">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:-**

```css
/*Adding overflow hidden*/
.scrollable-div{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Yes its that easy. Just give your scrollable div a **overflow: hidden.** You don't need to use any Javascript code for it.

In your case you can simply do this:

```css
body{
 overflow: hidden;
}
```